# Separation of variables with three independent variables

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I have the following differential equations problem:

> Derive sets of three ordinary differential equations from the
>   following partial differential equation by separation of variables:
>   $$yu_{xx} + xu_{yy} + xyu_{zz} = 0,$$ where $u$ is a function of $x, y$ and $z$.

I'm supposed to "peel off" the independent variables one at a time I guess. I think first I need to use the information that $u(x,y,z) = X(x)v(y,z)$ and then use the information that $v(y,z) = Y(y)Z(z)$, so $u(x,y,z) = X(x)Y(y)Z(z)$.

I haven't done before separation of variables with more than two independent variables. Can someone show me how it's done?

Thnx for any help =)

**UPDATE**:

Correct answer from my book:

$$X'' = c_1xX, \;\;\;\;Y''=c_2yY, \;\;\;\; Z'' = -(c_1+c_2)Z$$

Comment: First of all divide through by xy. Then insert the u =XYZ. Then divide through by u. Once that's done proceed as usual with the caveat that unlike the 2d version where you have a single integration constant usual $\lambda^2$ , you will have two.

Comment: +1 Thank you for your help @Chinny84. Can you check my answer, I tried to use my reference as guide, but I'm not confident enough if it's correct or not =D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried it myself...is this valid?:

$$yu_{xx} + xu_{yy} + xyu_{zz} = 0$$

Insert: $u(x,y,z) = X(x)v(y,z), \;\; v(y,z) = Y(y)Z(z) $

$$yX''(x)v + xX(x)v_{yy} + xyX(x)v_{zz} = 0 $$

$$\frac{yX''(x)v}{xX(x)} + v_{yy} + yv_{zz} = 0$$
$$\frac{X''(x)}{xX(x)} = \frac{-v_{yy} - yv_{zz}}{yv}$$

Because $x, y$ and $z$ are independent variables it must be that:

$$\frac{X''(x)}{xX(x)} = \frac{-v_{yy} - yv_{zz}}{yv} =\lambda^2,$$

for some constant $\lambda^2$. Now we set $v = Y(y)Z(z)$ for the right side of the equation:

$$\frac{-Y''(y)Z(z)-yY(y)Z''(z)}{yY(y)Z(z)} = \lambda^2$$

$$\frac{-Y''(y)}{yY(y)}-\frac{Z''(z)}{Z(z)} = \lambda^2$$

$$\frac{-Y''(y)}{yY(y)} = \lambda^2+\frac{Z''(z)}{Z(z)}$$

because $z$ and $y$ are independent we know that:

$\displaystyle \frac{-Y''(y)}{yY(y)} = b^2 \;\;$ and $\;\;\displaystyle \lambda^2+\frac{Z''(z)}
{Z(z)} = b^2 $

So I get:

$$X''(x) = xX(x)\lambda^2$$
$$-Y''(y) = yY(y)b^2$$
$$Z''(z) = (b^2-\lambda^2)Z(z),$$

for some constants $\lambda^2$ and $b^2$.

Comment: This looks about right. The only thing I would change is that fact that we tend to use $\lambda^{2}$ or $A^{2}$ if you want, as it is better to see instead of $\sqrt{A}$'s everywhere.

Comment: +1 @Chinny84 okay :) I will keep that in mind. Thank you! Appreciate! I will change $A$ and $B$ to $\lambda^2$ and $b^2$ =)

Comment: +1 @Chinny84 I will =) thank you for reminding me, there's just this thing that I need to wait two days before I can accept my own answer =) stack.exchange won't allow me to accept it before that.

Comment: I have never asked a question on here, so I didn't realise lol. It will give a chance for other members to query it as well. Did you get the right solution in the end?

Comment: +1 No probs lol ;D Yes that's true. I will post the correct answer from my book =) I guess I did it right. I didn't even check it before you asked x) It seems pretty much correct...something maybe different in the very last one involving $Z$ (the constants), check my updated post =) I used the exact same notation as my book.