# Separation of variables for a Second Order PDE with three variables

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative, harmonic-functions

I am fairly new to PDEs and would like some hints on how to approach a particular question.

I have been given six boundary conditions for the equation below (L can be assumed to be a known constant):

$\ \partial^2 f(x,y,z)/\partial x^2 + \partial^2 f(x,y,z)/\partial y^2 + \partial^2 f(x,y,z)/\partial z^2  - 1/L^2 f(x,y,z) =0 \ $
[equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yiSsr.png)

I would like to fix the analytical solution for $\ f(x,y,z) \ $, but am unsure of how to approach this kind of problem with three independent variables along with
 $\ - 1/L^2 f(x,y,z) \ $ term.

I have only really dealt with two independent variables in the form

$\ \partial^2 f(x,y)/\partial x^2 + \partial^2 f(x,y)/\partial y^2 =0 \ $

I am not sure how to deal the $\ - 1/L^2 f(x,y,z) \ $ term and would like to ask what is the best way to approach this problem.  I know I should be using the separation of variables method, but don't know the intermediate step to deal with the equation I have and get it into $\ \partial^2 f(x,y,z)/\partial x^2 + \partial^2 f(x,y,z)/\partial y^2 + \partial^2 f(x,y,z)/\partial z^2 =0 \ $

I am not entirely sure how to deal with $ \ - 1/L^2 f(x,y,z) \ $ term

Once I find out how, I plan to follow the approach outlined in 
[Separation of variables with three independent variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/688382/separation-of-variables-with-three-independent-variables)

Thanks for reading and hope you can help!
Cheers

Comment: Set $f(x,y,z)=X(x)Y(y)Z(z)$, and divide everything by $f$, which is to say $XYZ$. You'll end up with a $\frac{1}{L^2}$ term that you can pull into the first separation equation, or into a later one. Which separated equation you pull it into won't change the final outcome, even though things may look a little different in the form of the constants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\frac{\partial^2 f(x,y,z)}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2 f(x,y,z)}{\partial y^2} + \frac{\partial^2 f(x,y,z)}{\partial z^2}  - \frac{1}{L^2} f(x,y,z) =0  \tag 1$
Separation of variables means that you are looking for particular solutions on a particular form :
$$f(x,y,z)=X(x)Y(y)Z(z)$$
Putting it into Eq.$(1)$ leads to :
$$X''YZ+ y''XZ+Z''XY-\frac{1}{L^2} XYZ=0$$
$$\frac{X''}{X}+\frac{Y''}{Y}+\frac{Z''}{Z}-\frac{1}{L^2}=0$$
This implies that each term is constant :
$$\begin{cases}
\frac{X''}{X}=\alpha \quad\to\quad \frac{d^2X}{dx^2}=\alpha\: X(x)\\
\frac{Y''}{Y}=\beta \quad\to\quad \frac{d^2Y}{dy^2}=\beta\: Y(y)\\
\frac{Z''}{Z}=\gamma \quad\to\quad \frac{d^2Z}{dz^2}=\gamma\: Z(z)\\
\end{cases} \qquad \text{with}\qquad \alpha+\beta+\gamma=\frac{1}{L^2}$$

Solve the three ODEs respectively for $X(x)$ , $Y(y)$ and $Z(z)$.

The parameters $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$ appear into them. So we will write them as : $X_\alpha(x)$, $Y_\beta(y)$, $Z_\gamma(z)$

The particular solution obtained is :
$$f(x,y,z)=X_\alpha(x) Y_\beta(y) Z_\gamma(z) \qquad \text{with}\qquad \alpha+\beta+\gamma=\frac{1}{L^2}$$

Of course this is not the general solution of Eq.$(1)$. Any linear combination of the above particular solutions is a solution of Eq.$(1)$ .

Then, all depends on the boundary conditions, in order to determine the convenient linear combination. Generally, this is the most difficult part of the task.

Comment: brilliant thanks!